# merge on target table by comparing source and target table both

Tags: oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Do we have provision of matching source and target table both in oracle

I have three condition:

1. when source and target matches then update on condition
2. When New data in source which is not in target then add the record.
3. When data is not there in source but in target. Then update the flag in target table.

Please note: Source table is refreshed every day.

I am able to do step 1 and step 2 in merge like below

```
merge into target as t using Source as S
      On t.pk1 = s.pk1 and t1.pk2 = s.pk2
when matched and t.normalKey <> s.NormalKey --Step 1
    then update t.normalKey = s.NormalKey
when not matched 
    then insert (t.field) values (s.field) --Step 2
Step 3-- ?
```

There is a way of handling this in sql server. as below
I am trying to figure out same way of using 'By' clause in Snowflake.

Below is the example we do in sqlserver.

```
MERGE <target_table> [AS TARGET]
USING <table_source> [AS SOURCE]
ON <search_condition>
[WHEN MATCHED 
   THEN <merge_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED [BY TARGET]
   THEN <merge_not_matched> ]
[WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE
   THEN <merge_matched> ];
```

My final solution will be to use another merge/update statement.
First Merge to handle step 1 and 2.

and another Update just to handle step 3.

Or do we have a better way.

Comment: Is this query related to Snowflake sql?

Comment: yes, Basically I am trying this SnowSql

Comment: What is the purpose of updating the target table if the data isn't in the source?  And can you provide more information on the source table?  Is it change data only, or is it always a full refresh of the data.  How does it relate to the target table?  Snowflake MERGE doesn't behave the same as SQL Server.  It is used to MERGE source into target, while SQL Server is more about comparing 2 tables and applying logic.  So there is not BY SOURCE or BY TARGET option available in Snowflake.

Comment: @MikeWalton `What is the purpose of updating the target table if the data isn't in the source? And can you provide more information on the source table?` Common scenario is "soft delete" and setting flag `is_deleted`. Anoter one is setting `end date`(if handling date periods). The target table could contain **metadata columns** so UPDATE has the meaning even if the source does not contain that row.

Comment: I understand the general purpose, I was asking for the OP's purpose, since it wasn't in the question.  There are other solutions, but I wanted to be focused on the use-case.

Comment: The Target table is a change system table.. I understand it is not a good design but I am migrating from oracle to snowflake.. Where client in the first step is reluctant to see same tables in snowflake. Once It is done we will be working on newer approach..